# ACL allowing admin not being searched

Tags: acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to adapt what I learned from the access control examples into a really simple api that right now has an admin user account that can log in and create a "publication".  I am able to log the user in and get an access token, however, when I attempt to post to my publication endpoint I keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` error. I've been stuck on this pretty much all day long. I've been searching and haven't found any info on this issue. Help would be appreciated.

The following is the output when I run
`DEBUG=loopback:security:* slc run`:

```
lopback:security:role isInRole(): admin +10s
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
loopback:security:access-context principals: +0ms
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":1} +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelName publication +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined +0ms
loopback:security:access-context property create +0ms
loopback:security:access-context method create +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessType WRITE +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
loopback:security:access-context   id "HtEgTxkSSROIJEfZiB3AObXnWVGGZ0VoFkNDX7jie8HHZh8nHv5vNzGDEgNWiBCb" +0ms
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 1 +0ms
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true +0ms
loopback:security:role isInRole(): $everyone +1ms
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
loopback:security:access-context principals: +0ms
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":1} +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelName publication +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined +0ms
loopback:security:access-context property create +0ms
loopback:security:access-context method create +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessType WRITE +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
loopback:security:access-context   id "HtEgTxkSSROIJEfZiB3AObXnWVGGZ0VoFkNDX7jie8HHZh8nHv5vNzGDEgNWiBCb" +1ms
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 1 +0ms
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true +0ms
loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $everyone +0ms
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":1,"name":"admin","created":"2014-12-17T21:02:30.442Z","modified":"2014-12-17T21:02:30.442Z"} +0ms
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null +2ms
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: false +0ms
loopback:security:acl The following ACLs were searched:  +0ms
loopback:security:acl ---ACL--- +0ms
loopback:security:acl model publication +0ms
loopback:security:acl property * +0ms
loopback:security:acl principalType ROLE +1ms
loopback:security:acl principalId $everyone +0ms
loopback:security:acl accessType * +0ms
loopback:security:acl permission DENY +0ms
loopback:security:acl with score: +0ms 7495
loopback:security:acl ---Resolved--- +0ms
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessRequest--- +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  model publication +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  property create +1ms
loopback:security:access-context  accessType WRITE +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  permission DENY +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  isWildcard() false +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  isAllowed() false +0ms
```

**common/models/publication.json**

```
{
  "name": "publication",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }

  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

**server/database.json**

```
{
  "ids": {
    "User": 1,
    "AccessToken": 2,
    "ACL": 1,
    "RoleMapping": 1,
    "Role": 1,
    "publication": 1,
    "account": 3
  },
  "models": {
    "User": {},
    "AccessToken": {
  "HtEgTxkSSROIJEfZiB3AObXnWVGGZ0VoFkNDX7jie8HHZh8nHv5vNzGDEgNWiBCb": "{\"id\":\"HtEgTxkSSROIJEfZiB3AObXnWVGGZ0VoFkNDX7jie8HHZh8nHv5vNzGDEgNWiBCb\",\"ttl\":1209600,\"created\":\"2014-12-17T21:02:48.103Z\",\"userId\":1}"
    },
    "ACL": {},
    "RoleMapping": {
      "1": "{\"id\":1,\"principalType\":\"USER\",\"roleId\":1}"
    },
    "Role": {
      "1": "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"admin\",\"created\":\"2014-12-17T21:02:30.442Z\",\"modified\":\"2014-12-17T21:02:30.442Z\"}"
    },
    "publication": {},
    "account": {
      "1": "{\"fullname\":\"Jane Doe\",\"username\":\"janed\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$PWkG/Y.Jb9w25xtxZwUt/.WOQRZTVgIdKTalGVoCyBE3PoDqD9tK6\",\"email\":\"jane.doe@example.com\",\"id\":1}",
      "2": "{\"fullname\":\"John Doe\",\"username\":\"johnd\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$dD6r9NmV18R.epAg8.FuvuluQoJfIPMnUw9nGVFivu94PeKp0aKja\",\"email\":\"john.doe@example.com\",\"id\":2}"
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**:

Some progress, I noticed that my principal id of the role mapping wasn't being set when creating my test data. I have fixed that, however, the role mapping still isn't being found.

**Edit 2**:

Actually that was indeed the problem, I was testing the wrong end point after I fixed the `principalId`. Testing the create endpoint now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when setting up my test data I wasn't setting the principal id properly. I was using

```
var accounts = [{ 
    username: 'janed',
    email: 'jane.doe@example.com',
    fullname: 'Jane Doe',
    password: 'secret'  
  }, {
    username: 'johnd',
    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
    fullname: 'John Doe',
    password: 'secret'  
  }];

accounts.forEach(function (account) {
  Account.create(account, function(err, result) {
    //...
        role.principals.create({
          principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
          principalId: account.id // <-- undefined! should use result.id
        });
    //...
```

Once I switch the principal id to use `result.id` the ACL began to work.

Comment: Yup, had the same issue, myself, and similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully using loopback from past 4 months and in a very high traffic app, even I faced this acl issue in the starting , if you check in the log that you have mentioned it is clearly showing that the access is not allowed.

```
loopback:security:acl permission DENY +0ms
loopback:security:access-context  permission DENY +0ms
```

Few things that you can do to check it out,

1. give the create access to $everyone first and check whether its working or not, then you can change the access to $authenticated, and check, if later one is working then it means, ACL's are fine, and there is some issue with the role or role mapping.
2. try to create an acl for the first time using the acl generator :-`slc loopback:acl`
   It will guide you to create the acl on its own.